# How to calculate average weekly active visitor using DAX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

**Take note that `Visit 1` means the first visit of the day while `Visit 2` means the 2nd visit for the day.*

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to calculate average weekly active visitors in PowerBI using DAX.

First, I need to calculate how many unique visitors visit the shop in one week (Mon-Sun). Based on the calendar, `5/10/2022 - 5/13/2022` will be categorized under one week, and `5/16/2022 - 5/18/2022` is another week. So for the week from `5/10/2022 - 5/13/2022`, there are 9 unique visitor and for the week from `5/16/2022 - 5/18/2022`, there are 3 unique visitors.

Once I found out the unique visitor for respective weeks, then I can get the average weekly active visitor by:

`(9+3)/2 = 6 visitors`

Hence, the answer for the example in the screenshot will be 6 visitors. The output will be used in  card visualization.

Struggling to find the best way to do this, any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Sample Data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10TsJUy-Lkdpb9Eeh5itx-XE59hytC_i5I_6UeLLHS84/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about DAX (or Power BI) to devise a DAX only solution.

However, you can calculate the Distinct Visitors per week using Power Query M Code (Home=>Transform in Power BI), and then create a Measure to show the Average visitors per week on the card.

***Power Query M Code***
*Edit: Change from computing `weeknumber` to computing `start of week` to avoid problems if dates span more than a year, per comment below by **@weizer***

```
let

//change next line to whatever your actual source is
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Don't need this column for the output
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Visit"}),

//Set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Visitor ID", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}}),

//add custom column referenced to "StartOfWeek" so we can group by week
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "WeekNumber", each Date.StartOfWeek([Date],Day.Monday), type date),

//Group by week number
//  Then aggregate by week range and distinct visitor count
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"WeekNumber"}, {
        {"Date Range", each Date.ToText(List.Min([Date])) & " - " & Date.ToText(List.Max([Date])), type text},
        {"Distinct Visitors", each List.Count(List.Distinct([Visitor ID])), Int64.Type}
        }),

//Remove unneeded Weeknumber column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"WeekNumber"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

The Measure for the card will be just a simple Average function:

```
Distinct Visitors per Week = Average(yourTableName[Distinct Visitors])
```

[image]

Comment: I saw that you use week number in your M query, I'm afraid that it will affect the next year data as the week number will be reused when the new calendar year started

Comment: @weizer Thanks for pointing that out.  Probably a better formula would be `Date.StartOfWeek([Date],Day.Monday)`

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR days = 
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Sheet1'
            ,'Sheet1'[Date]
        )
VAR Calend=
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            days
            ,"week",WEEKNUM('Sheet1'[Date])
        )
VAR weeks= 
        SUMMARIZE(
            Calend
            ,[week]
            ,"qty",COUNTROWS(VALUES('Sheet1'[Visitor ID]))
        )         
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(
        weeks
        ,[qty]
    )
```